# Two bar plots in one graph from different dataframes (one common column)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have two simple data frames

1.

```
count type
400   customer
1200  subscriber
```

2.

```
count type
2000  customer
5000  subscriber
```

I am trying to make **bar plot** with one figure.

***X axis***: customer - customer, subscriber - subscriber -> same type next to each other)

***Y axis***: count

I tried

```
df1.plot.bar()
df2.plot.bar()
```

and stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) the data together:

```
combined = df1.merge(df2, on="type", suffixes=["1", "2"]).set_index("type")
```

Then you can plot them with one call:

```
combined.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the other elegant answer. However, since you have tagged `matplotlib`, you might be interested in knowing a corresponding solution. The idea here is to align the bars to the edges of major ticks and then use negative and positive width to shift them left/right.

P.S: This is a tailored solution for plotting two bars adjacently. In principle, this can be made general to plot multiple bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(df1['type'], df1['count'], align='edge', width=-0.3, label='count1')
plt.bar(df2['type'], df2['count'], align='edge', width=0.3, label='count2')

plt.legend()
```

[image]